# Modifying state object without calling setState, but object method instead

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using a class inside my "useState" hook, and this class has a method to modify its content, here is a (quick) example :

```
class Test {

    foo: string;

    constructor() {
        this.foo = 'foo';
    }

    modifyFoo() {
        this.foo = 'bar';
    }

}
.........

const [test, setTest] = useState(new Test());

test.modifyFoo();
.........
```

Is calling the method "modifyFoo" considered bad practice ?

I usually never modify an object without using setState, but in my personal case it is useful because I do not want to redeclare my class.

Comment: You should *always* use `setTest` to update `test`. What if you want to re-render the component when `test` changes? Then you would have to rewrite all the mutations into `setTest`. Why not do it right the first time? Also, you would have less bugs when trying to use other things like `useEffect` and `useMemo` with `test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is calling the method "modifyFoo" considered bad practice ?

As always, it depends. But generally yes.

Think about what it would take to *write* React itself, put yourself in the shoes of the React team at Meta. For performance's sake you don't want to re-render if nothing has changed, but doing deep equality checks for reference types is expensive too and in the general case potentially ambiguous. So you compromise: you either check if the reference has changed (like in props) and/or you offer API hooks for the *user* to call to tell you something changed.

*That* is what the setter from `useState` and the `setState` method of class components is for: to tell React "hey I'm changing this thing, re-render the things that rely on it".

Because of the semantics, it is generally considered best practice to *never* mutate data that React relies on (i.e. data dependencies of your views).

React I believe gets its name in part from [functional reactive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming#:%7E:text=Functional%20reactive%20programming%20(FRP)%20is,map%2C%20reduce%2C%20filter), and even if I'm wrong about the origin of the name the design choices definitely resonate. Old-school OO code just isn't really a great fit and when dealing with third party APIs that are written that way (e.g. [the Google Maps API](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react)) the generally accepted practice is to write functionalish Reacty wrappers for it.

So if you really don't want to change your class or `new` up a fresh instance every time (and there are certainly cases where you wouldn't) you *could* always write React component wrappers for it rather than trying to use it directly.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I just do not understand what you mean by "you could always write React component wrappers for it rather than trying to use it directly." Do you maybe have a website talking about it ?

Comment: @A.Vinuela [Try the top few hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=writing+react+wrappers+for+imperative+apis&oq=writing+react+wrappers+for+imperative+apis&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160l5.6812j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Or look at the aforementioned [Google Maps API React wrappers](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react). Basically you want to hide the imperative manipulations behind a declarative facade.